# Laravel Query Builder result object is throwing "Trying to get property of non-object" exception

Tags: php, laravel-4, query-builder

This is one of those headscratchers where the error message is directly contradicted by the evidence on hand.  I have the following method in a Laravel model called `Family`, which has an `id` field:

```
public function getFamilyName()
{
    $search_id = ( empty( $this->primary_id ) ) ? $this->id : $this->primary_id;
    $names = DB::select( 
        'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`last_name` ORDER BY `last_name` SEPARATOR \'/\' ) `name_list` 
        FROM (SELECT `last_name` 
              FROM `children`  
              WHERE `primary_id` IS NULL  
              AND `family_id`=?  
              UNION  
              SELECT `last_name`  
              FROM `parents`  
              WHERE `primary_id` IS NULL  
              AND `family_id`=?) `last_names`', 
        array($search_id, $search_id) );
    $nameList = $names[0]->name_list;
    return ($nameList=="") ? 'Unnamed': $nameList;
}
```

This code has worked fine until earlier today, but is now throwing a   *Trying to get property of non-object* exception at
      `$nameList = $names[0]->name_list`.

I hadn't touched the method, so I'm at a loss as to what's gone wrong.  I've done some quick and dirty investigation via thrown Exceptions using print_r, and determined the following:

- For the family I'm working with, `print_r($names)` resolves to
  `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name_list] => Esper-Smith/Smith ) )`
- `print_r($names[0])` resolves to
  `stdClass Object ( [name_list] => Esper-Smith/Smith )`
- `print_r($names[0]->name_list)` resolves to `'Esper-Smith/Smith'`
- `print_r(is_object($names[0]))` returns 1

So why am I getting an Exception that `$names[0]` is a non-object?  Why is an Exception being thrown for an expression that can successfully be resolved by a `print_r()` call?  I don't like it when my code starts getting cute...

Comment: Is this somehow called in **Loop**?

Comment: Nope, in this instance the method is called one time for a single family.

Comment: do one thing, `if(!isset($names[0]->name_list)){ print_r($names); die()}`, you will know

Comment: Huh, unlike what I would expect based on what I posted above, I get `Array ( [0] => Array ( [name_list] => Esper-Smith/Smith ) )`, so the stdClass Object element is being reported out as an Array here.  Weird...

Comment: Damn, one more puzzle to solve, why **array** ?

Comment: Weirder:  I replaced `$nameList=$names[0]->name_list;` with `$nameList = $names[0]['name_list'];`, which should work according to the results of your suggestion, and it throws an Exception `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`.  So, `$names[0]` is apparently neither an Object nor an Array.  WTF?

Comment: Damn, Damn. look up man and also post reason here.

Comment: Make sure you're not changing the default `fetchMode` setting between queries.

Comment: Give @apokryfos a cigar!  I had added a setFetchMode() call elsewhere in the code yesterday.  Add this as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DB::Select wraps around `PDO` and makes use of the `fetchMode` property to choose between object or array, you need to ensure that your `fetchMode` is properly set before executing your queries.

The Laravel `Connection` implements method `setFetchMode` which sets the default connection mode. This change will persist for all the remainder of the script execution so if you change it somewhere you need to remember to change it back to how the rest of your code expects it to be.

Comment: Thanks, the thought that the query behavior could have changed due to code outside the method hadn't occurred to me.